# What's the best user/permission setup on Linux for a folder PHP can write to?

Tags: php, linux, apache, permissions

After years of using `chmod 777` to solve PHP write permission woes, I want to know the proper way of solving the problem.

I have a website on my server owned by `user1` in group `user1`. There is a folder in this website called `uploads`.

Normally to get writing with PHP to work, I have to `chmod` this folder to `777`. But I obviously recognise this is dangerous and incorrect, and I want to setup the permissions properly to minimise risk.

From my limited knowledge, I see two options,

1. I `chown` the `uploads` folder so that it's owned by `apache`. This way, I can just use the default permissions and `apache` can happily write to the folder.
2. I add a second group to `apache` of `user1`. I then give write permission to the owner and group on `uploads`, which should allow `apache` to write to `uploads`?

**My question is, what is the best approach?** Is it one of the above or something completely different?

If the best solution is #1, how can `user1` also write to uploads over SFTP as that solution will not let them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my current company, we set the apache group to the group that owns the folder, so you just need to do `chmod 770` on the folder to give permissions to that particular group to do funny stuff on that folder.

However you still to remember to protect your application from malicious user, as the PHP script being run, if sufficiently insecure, can still do damage to the folder.

Comment: So you're saying my second option might be best? Adding `apache` to a second group of `user1` and changing the permission on the folder so owner and group can write?

Answer (score 1):

If it's your own server, the best way is to set the folder to the group apache uses, e.g. with `chgrp www-data` on debian (might be different on other systems). You usually have to do this as root or at least as a user who has access to his own and www-data group. If your user has access to www-data group, this might be a cool feature for you since its easy then to read and maybe write/move the files.
In this case, use 770 as the file permission and ensure that files created by php get this permission (either explicitly after creating with chmod or with umask before creation. See php manual for both.)

If you are working on a shared hosting environment, the only clean solution I know is [mod_suexec](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_suexec.html), but I don't know many hosters that enable it. If this is not available I know only the way you do know, working with 777. Often, your home directory in shared environments have a longer random string in the path name so that others should not find your directory and therefore can't access your files. But this is not real security.. ;-)

Good luck
Michel